# Organize data on hybrid-mobile-app

Tags: json, data-structures, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an Ionic app that must be able to operate offline. Being so I receive from the backend a JSON object called data that contains all the info I need and this object get updated at times using a diff algorithm.

The data comes like that:

```
{
   "foos": [
     {"id": 1, "name": "foo1"},
     {"id": 2, "name": "foo2"}
   ],
   "bars": [
     {"id": 1, "name": "bar1", "fooId": 1},
     {"id": 2, "name": "bar2", "fooId": 2}
   ]
}
```

I would like to have a specialized layer from where I can call for example `findFooById(bars[i].fooId)`

I am wondering what is the best way to achieve that and if there is something out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best solution is to revisit your data structure in general as it looks overly complicated and I can't see a benefit to it.

But, general algorithm would be easy:

```
function findFooById(fooId) {
  for (var x = 0; x < foos.length; x++){
    if (foos[x].id == fooId) { return foos[x]; }
  }
  return false;
}
```